# Measuring packet per second for connected clients IP addresses

Tags: python, c++, sockets, network-programming, winsock

How can we determine the packet rate of clients connected to our server in case of multi client server using Winsock. The idea I came up with is keeping a frequency map for IP addresses of all the clients and storing the packets count for some arbitrary amount k seconds. Now after k seconds we traverse the map and see what IP addresses have more than 100*k packets, now we block these IP addresses. After every k seconds we empty the map and start again.
PSEUDO CODE:  (k = 10)

```
map<string,int> map;

void calculate() {
  for(auto &ip : map){
     if(ip.second>10000) blacklist(ip.first);
  }
  map.clear();
  Sleep(10000);
  calculate();
}

int s = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
// bind(), listen()

calculate();

while(1) {
  if(recv(s,buff,len)>0) map[client.ip]++;
  
}
```

Comment: You have a TCP socket. There's no concept of "packets per second" in TCP that makes sense for applications. Because the receive side has a lot of influence on that.  `recv` doesn't consume a packet as it would with UDP. It consumes up to `len` bytes into the TCP stream.  **WHAT ARE YOU REALLY TRYING TO DO?**

Comment: The first statement, right out of the gate is "How can we determine <X>". That is followed by describing one possible implementation of <X>". Sounds like you've answered your own question. Except for a couple of major design flaws, including both actual (the shown code that blacklists individual counters, rather than IP addresses) and logical. There are a number of logical flaws in the overall algorithm, however that's a part of every good learning experience. This is the best way to learn something: try to do it, discover the logical flaws yourself, and learn from them.

Comment: If you're trying to block a remote TCP node from sending too fast, then just throttle the frequency in which you invoke recv.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, sorry about that map error, I did that in hurry but I've fixed the code now. I agree with your point that this is the right way to learn but I think I've spent too much time figuring out this without any success :( So could you please help me rectify the flaws?

Comment: @selbie What I'm really trying to do is 1) if a tcp node after  handshake ofc, sends too many data units(which I thought are known as packets) to flood/jam our server resources then I wish to block that IP address from my server. and 2) if from some IP address I'm getting udp DATAGRAMS at a very high rate, then I wish to block that too from communicating with the server in future

Comment: @SamVarshavchik my original and specific question was "how to measure rate of packet transmission" which I thought would be wrong to directly ask without any homework so I designed this algorithm and shared it with the community to seek help. If this is not a help site then how come everyone is posting problems where they are stuck at and waiting for people to ANSWER (or help) that :/

Comment: Also @selbie, f someone is sending too fast, I'd like to block him permanently rather than receiving his messages less frequently. Something like this is what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: What argument? It's just friendly chit-chat. I'm just pointing out that this is not a good question for Stackoverflow, and you're unlikely to get a good answer here. So far it looks like I'm being proven right.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246126/discussion-between-chirag-arora-and-sam-varshavchik).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per comments:

> If someone is sending too fast, I'd like to block him permanently rather than receiving his messages less frequently. Something like this is what I'm trying to achieve

If this was UDP, I'd 100% be onboard with what you are trying to do and give the code I have.  But this is TCP and your assumptions are flawed.

Let's say the sender invokes this:

`send(sock, buffer, 1000, 0);`

And then on the other side, you invoke this:

`recv(sock, buffer, 1000, 0)`

Did you know that recv may do any of the following:

- It may return any value less than or equal to 1000. It could return `1` and expect you to invoke it another 999 times to consume the entire message. One of the biggest confusions with TCP socket is assuming that each `send` call mirrors a `recv` call in a 1:1 fashion. Lots of buggy apps have shipped that way.
- More probably, you'll get 1 or 2 recv calls because of IP fragmentation and/or TCP segmentation. How fast you invoke `recv` also  But this is never guaranteed or expected to be consistent. What you observe with local testing on your on LAN will not resemble actual internet behavior.
- How many recv calls you get has nothing to do with how many actual IP packets or TCP segments, because "the packets" will get coalesced anyway by the TCP stack on the recv side.
- Similarly, how many bytes you pass to `send` doesn't influence the packet count. TCP, including any number of routers and gateways in between, may split up this 1000 byte stream into additional fragments and segments.

I'm going to offer two suggestions:

1. Detect flood attacks by counting **application protocol messages** and/or the size of these application protocol messages -  but not individual `recv` calls.  That is, as you `recv` data, you'll accumulate this data stream into logical protocol messages based on a fixed size of bytes or a delimiter based message structure and pass it up to a higher part of your application for processing.  Do the incremental count then.
2. Instead of trying to thwart flood attacks at the message level, it's probably simpler to just throttle clients to a fixed rate of data. That is, each time you `recv` data, count how many bytes it returns and use with a timer to measure an incoming bytes/second rate.  If the remote side exceeds your limit, insert sleep statements in between recv calls. This will implicitly make TCP slow the other side down from sending too fast.

Comment: Woah I was totally unaware of how the TCP protocol might break the recv() calls. And I read more about the TCP and found out that rate limiting is not necessarily needed for TCP as it's implemented by default.
So I'd focus on the UDP stuff only, and in case of UDP, does receiver receive in one recvfrom() call corresponding to each sendto() (ofc if not buffer overflow occurs and everything runs fine)

Comment: Correct. In UDP, there is a one to one correspondence between `sendto` and `recvfrom`.  UDP is a "packet" protocol.